# complex sorting on python ,very trivial but interesting bug

Tags: python, sorting

I wanted to sort with 'sets' or 'a'. I try with the information below .

```
>>> sorted(student_objects, key=attrgetter('grade', 'age'))
[('john', 'A', 15), ('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12)]
```

http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

That function works with 'count' but not with 'sets', 'a'.

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, sets, count, a):
        self.sets = sets
        self.count = count
        self.a = a
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.sets, self.count, self.a))


number_object=[([1, 3, 7], 2, 3), ([3, 7], 2, 2), ([2, 4], 2, 2), ([1, 7], 9, 2), ([1, 3], 2, 2), (7, 2, 0), (4, 2, 0), (3, 3, 0), (2, 2, 0), (1, 2, 0)]
```

I wanted to use the one below, but it doesn't work. I use the same way the webpage introduce.

```
sorted(student_objects, key=attrgetter('sets', 'count'))
```

Funny thing is that count can work, but not the other one.

After trying several time, I decide to use another way. I can get the same result with this instruction.

```
s=sorted(number_object, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True )
sorted(s, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True )
```

But I am curious why the original one doesn't work. is there anyone who is good at python??

Comment: You are trying to use lists of different lengths as search keys.  How do you expect them to be sorted in any meaningful manner?  What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: `sorted(**student**_objects, key=attrgetter('sets', 'count'))` ?

Comment: This really doesn't make much sense.  Your `number_object` doesn't use your `Number` class at all.  What do you expect to happen if you don't use the class you defined?

Comment: 'is there anyone who is good at python?' Good question, not easy to answer.

Comment: The "bug" is neither trivial nor interesting.  It appears that the "bug" is a failure to actually create objects of the expected class.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the  link you gave, you will realize you must instantiate your objects like this:

```
number_objects = [Number([1, 3, 7], 2, 3),
                  Number([3, 7], 2, 2), 
                  .......
                 ]
```

then,

```
sorted(number_objects, key=attrgetter('sets', 'count'))
```

should work.

For example:

```
from operator import attrgetter
class Number:
    def __init__(self, sets, count, a):
        self.sets = sets
        self.count = count
        self.a = a
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.sets, self.count, self.a))


number_objects = [Number([1, 3, 7], 2, 3), Number([3, 7], 2, 2),
                  Number([2, 4], 2, 2), Number([1, 7], 9, 2), 
                  Number([1, 3], 2, 2)]

print sorted(number_objects, key=attrgetter('sets', 'count'))
```

produces:

```
[([1, 3], 2, 2), ([1, 3, 7], 2, 3), ([1, 7], 9, 2), ([2, 4], 2, 2), ([3, 7], 2,
2)]
```